# Geometric probabilities with rectangle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, definite-integrals, geometric-probability

One side of rectangle is 1.2 other is 3.9. We randomly pick points on adjacent sides and then draw a stretch through them. What is the probability that the area of the received triangle is less than 1.15? I think that it could be:

> 1.15/1.2*3.9

But my teacher says that I have to use **integrals** in this exercise. Any hints and solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If I pick a point on the longer side, let's say it gives us a base of length $x$, then how tall can the height, $y$, be such that $A = \frac{1}{2}xy < 1.15\ $ holds? So how can you write $P(A < 1.15 | X = x)\ $ as a probability on $Y$ (that will be a function of $x$)?

So having done that, you then need to find the unconditional probability across all possible values of $x$, which is where you will need to integrate.

Comment: $y=2.30/x$ yes?

Comment: $\int (4,68-2.3/x)$ is it somewhere near? I don't get good integral bounds

Comment: could you help me, sir